# What's the meaning of the expression "Live the ride"

Tags: expressions, slang

I'm still learning some english slangs and expressions. I saw the expression "Live the ride".

I find nothing in the internet about that expression. Who uses that expression talk about to create something new everyday, do not have fear to try etc...

But when you talk about to "live the ride" you are talking about to live the life in your own way, to do what you want or to live to make something great, to have a purpose of life?

Thanks!

Comment: Your guesses are excellent. I never heard of it but you make sense of it.

Comment: Thanks, @YosefBaskin! I'm still trying to understand what this expression means... At my church i learned the expression to "Live for something greater". This made all the difference in my life. This is about to live not for you but to make what God craeted you to do and to be. I don't want to use an expression that means the oposite of that!

thanks!

Comment: "Live the Ride" appears to be the slogan of `bike198.com`, a website for people devoted to mountain biking. Its 'meaning' would be something like "enjoy the mountain bike experience".

Comment: Not all slang is worth learning. Good to know does not mean good to use. I'd use this one with caution.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, and KHS Bicycles, and very similar to "live to ride ... ride to live" (biker philosophy) which you'll also see on Harley-Davidson merchandise. In a nutshell it means riding is the only important thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a few slogans along these lines:

Rip Curl - Live the Search

As @StoneyB points out Bike 198 - Live the Ride

In any case, expressions in this form tend towards a meaning of enjoying the process, rather than the result. For example, Rip Curl is a surfing brand, and "Live the Search" refers to a never ending search for good (or perfect) waves. The perfect wave, the perfect ride, the perfect anything is subjective at best, and you may never find it, or it may not exist.